# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects f.write python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to make the script save the result to the save.txt file
I am running with python2.7 and they are writing an error

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "point9.py", line 7, in <module> f.write("" + data + "" + "\n") TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Code:

```
data = 3673256654

print(data)


f = open("save.txt", 'a') 
f.write("" + data + "" + "\n") 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression doesn't do what you want:

```
"" + data + "" + "\n"
```

Prefer

```
f"{data}\n"
```

Some years ago they
[sunsetted](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2)
the interpreter you're using.
I don't know offhand if f-strings
were ever back ported to python2.

You could use `str(data) + "\n"` for same effect.
Or any of the several `.format()` variants.
(Not sure why you appended empty string a couple
of times, as that does literally nothing.)